# IBM Watson Conversation use of '~'?

Tags: java, api, watson-conversation

I just saw in the doc this  :

`~ + Number`   *Specifies an approximate match by indicating the maximum number of single-character differences allowed between the query string and a match in the response object. For example,* `car~1` *would match* `car`, `cat`, *or* `cars`  *but it would not match* `cats`.

`request.input.text:Watson~3`

I tried to do the same in the bluemix dialog interface but I have got an error : 
  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (126) '~'`

The error is quite explicit, so does anyone know how to substitute the '~' symbol so the **levenshtein distance** operator works ?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about Conversation service REST API (
 https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/filter-reference.html)

I don't think that you can use it for triggers in the bluemix dialog interface

Couple of days ago they introduced fuzzy matching

> You can turn on fuzzy matching per entity to impove the ability of the
>   service to recognize terms in user input with syntax that is similar
>   to the entity, without requiring an exact match.

You can find more info about latest change here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/release-notes.html

Comment: This is the correct answer, although could be worded better. The OP is referring to the filtering options on the Logging API call. It is not used in dialog code. Fuzzy matching may offer similar functionality (but is not lev distance). It's also currently BETA, so don't assume it will work as expected until GA.